# Android RelativeLayout + TextView dynamically

Tags: android, layout, textview, layoutparams

I created a layout dynamically, inside TextView I want to display 2. It works, but how can I position the TextView, one right and one left? Thanks

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

RelativeLayout r_layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

r_layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

sv.addView(r_layout);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);

 int id1 = 1;
        tv1.setId(id1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv1.getId());

        tv2.setText(data.getStringExtra("prodotto"));
        tv1.setText(data.getStringExtra("prodotto"));

        r_layout.addView(tv2, p);



        layout_relativo.addView(sv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set ID to your first TextView using `setID()` method, then you need to add [RIGHT_OF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#RIGHT_OF) rule for 2nd TextView as given below.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv1.getId());
r_layout.addView(tv2, p);
```

Comment: I edited my post. The second TextView is not displayed